Multiple Slicers with Multiple Selection in each with AND condition in Power Bi
I am working on a model that filters items based on the criteria given in the slicers. In this I want to filter the item through three slicers

Hierarchy Slicer
Attribute Slicer
Attribute Value Slicer.

As an example, let's say in second slicer I want to filter an item using two attributes (STANDARD, FINISH) with values (ISO 4014, NO SURFACE TREATMENT). Meaning I want to filter (see) the item which has ISO 4014 as STANDARD and  NO SURFACE TREATMENT as FINISH. But when I try to do this (refer screen shot) it is not filtering for the 'AND' condition. It is filtering for 'OR' condition (i.e it filters all materials which has either NO SURFACE TREATMENT as FINISH 'OR' STANDARD as ISO 4014, which I don't want. I want to filter the material which has both NO SURFACE TREATMENT as FINISH and ISO 4014 as STANDARD.
How can I achieve my requirement?Snap from Power Bi Screen
I have tried applying the DAX measures in slicers as per these YouTube video and blog. But it didn't help.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tONOosN1xAs
2.https://radacad.com/slicer-with-and-condition-in-power-bi

I am open to any suggestions to achieve my end result.
My requirement is Just need to filter the items based on conditions in the slicers. To do that I have a first slicer (Hierarchy Slicer) which will bring the all items based on what is selected in that hierarchy slicer. in this case (Hexagonal Bolts), let's say, it filters out 1000 items (bolts) and shows in the table with all 1000 item's all 7 attributes (FINISH, GRADE, LENGTH, STANDARD, THREAD PITCh, THREAD SERIES, THREAD SIZE). (Refer below image)
Hierarchy filter alone applied
Now the second slicer comes up, where I want to filter from this 1000 bolts that has "FINISH" as 'NO SURFACE TREATMENT and STANDARD as "ISO 4014" - i.e an item which has attributes values as these two.
But currently if I select these two attributes as multiple selection (FINISH, STANDARD) and values from the third slicer (Attribute values slicer), the table appears with all bolts which either has NO SURFACE TREATMENT "OR" ISO 4014 as STANDARD. (Refer image)
Applied Second and third filter
But I want to filter the item which has both these values as it attribute values from these slicers itself.  any suggestion? if any clarity required please post as reply.

Filter operation go to the value of a single column and apply the filter. Now HOW it is possible you check a column's value equal 1 and 2 at the same time? With AND condition and 2 value in the filter, you will always get FALSE for all rows. I think you need to adjust your logic.

@mkRabbani Please see the updated question to understand the requirement. Can u please help based on that?

It is not clear how your model is organized. Could you provide a scheme?
